# Play audio on button click in viewpager efficiently in android

Tags: android, audio, android-viewpager

In my application I am displaying around 30 animal images using viewpager. each page has full screen image and play sound button. Clicking on button will play displayed animals sound. So there are 30 different sound files in raw folder. how to play audio effectively when user press button? What to use mediaplayer or soundpool? and how to use it effectively? Please give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the song files in the raw folder and then on the button's onClick method execute the songs play.
You can use a switch case for different id's of button.